# How to get user control id inside another user control id?

Tags: javascript, user-controls

How can i get one user control id inside another user control. Using java script .
Please help me.

```
 window.onload = function CheckQueryString() 
 {      
  // here i want to get user control id

 }
```

Comment: Please share more details. Some code, maybe even a jsFiddle. Your answer cannot be answered in its current form, because it is too general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am correct in comprehending your question, you could do something like this

```
// get a handle on your original control 
var myControl = $('[id$="<controlID>"]'); 
// and then access it's properties 
var myRuntimeId = myControl.eq(0).attr('id');
```